# How to redirect from one action to another when action parameter are different?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with Index and Add actions; both of which have different parameters. Index just loads the form and after form gets filled "Add" saves the entries to the database. Saving is working fine. However, when there are some error while adding, I want to show the error in the same page and stay on that page. When i retrun view it tries to render \add (ie.Add action) and it throws error as it cannot find /Add page. I am using ValidationMessage for showing error. How to redirect from one action to another when action parameter are different?

Comment: Usually you would have two actions with same name, let's say "Insert". One is answering to HTTP GET (when user enters the insert page) and the other answers to HTTP POST. The post action, takes the model as a parameter and checks if the mode is valid, if it's not, it will just return a view and show errors. This way the problem you asked about is no longer a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

return View("Index", model)